# Remove multiple children from DOM (JS)

Tags: javascript, dom, iterator

I am trying to remove certain children from DOM by iterating through them. I have a table, and I am looping through the children and removing some like this:

```js
for (const row of table.children) {
  const testRow = row.children[2];
  if (testRow.textContent === "false") {
    table.removeChild(row);
  }
}
```

When this code is run, some of the children that meet the condition `testRow.textContent === "false"` are removed, but *other rows that meet the condition are not removed*.

Logging out `t.children.lengh` as the loop goes on reveals that the size is decreasing (due to the children being removed). My theory is that removing a child messes up the iterator. I tried rewriting this code as a for loop and got the same result: some children are "skipped over" and not removed.

Ideas on how to remove certain children of a DOM element (based on dynamically pulled data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.children` is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection); it gets updated as you change the document. You can convert it to a normal array so that changes to the DOM won't affect the contents that you're iterating through.

In the example below I've used the spread operator (`...`) to create the new array, but you could use Array.from instead e.g. `Array.from(tbody.children)`.

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');

console.log(tbody.children.constructor.name);

for (const row of [...tbody.children]) {
  const testRow = row.children[1];
  if (testRow.textContent === "false") {
    tbody.removeChild(row);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>true</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>false</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>false</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>true</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td><td>false</td></tr>
    <tr><td>F</td><td>true</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Because `[...tbody.children]` is a normal array you can use functions like filter and forEach if you like, e.g.:

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');

[...tbody.children]
  .filter((row) => row.cells[1].textContent === "false")
  .forEach((row) => { tbody.removeChild(row); });
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>true</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>false</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>false</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>true</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td><td>false</td></tr>
    <tr><td>F</td><td>true</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `deleteRow` taking the index of the row and using a traditional `for` loop iterating backwards from the end of the table rows to the beginning, it also utilizes the `rows` property of the table element:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   const tbl = document.querySelector('table');
   for(let a = tbl.rows.length - 1; a >= 0; a--){
      //you can modify this next condition to match what you want
      if(tbl.rows[a].cells[0].textContent === "Even"){
         tbl.deleteRow(a);
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Even</td></tr>
<tr><td>Odd</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution I found works for all DOM types (vs just tables in [Ryan Wilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72367681/8804293)). Just decrement the index each time a DOM object is removed so that it will re-run the loop for the new `i`th element (because the previous will have been removed):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < t.children.length; i++) {
  const row = table.children[i];
  const testRow = row.children[2];
  if (testRow.textContent === "false") {
    table.removeChild(row);
    i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you can just iterate backwards. My solution will work just the same if I switch it to use the `children` property along with `removeChild`. Since your example uses a `table`, why not use the table properties and functions?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are empty, you could use the css [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector:

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
    for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('tr td:empty')){
        el.remove()
    }
},2000)
```

```css
td {border: 1px solid black;height:30px;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>text</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>text</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>

</table>
```